# Jitsi Meet and Sendbird class conflicts

Tags: android, kotlin, jitsi-meet, sendbird

I want to integrate the Jitsi meeting and send-bird into my project. For that, I added the below dependencies.

```
implementation 'com.sendbird.sdk:sendbird-android-sdk:3.1.15'
implementation 'com.sendbird.sdk:sendbird-calls:1.8.0'
implementation('org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:6.0.0') {
     transitive = true
}
```

But when I am trying to run the project I'm getting the below errors.

```
> Task :app:dexBuilderDebug

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class org.webrtc.AndroidVideoDecoder found in modules jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.100.1-jitsi-11101599-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.100.1-jitsi-11101599) and jetified-sendbird-calls-1.8.0-runtime (com.sendbird.sdk:sendbird-calls:1.8.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.AndroidVideoDecoder$1 found in modules jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.100.1-jitsi-11101599-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.100.1-jitsi-11101599) and jetified-sendbird-calls-1.8.0-runtime (com.sendbird.sdk:sendbird-calls:1.8.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.AndroidVideoDecoder$DecodedTextureMetadata found in modules jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.100.1-jitsi-11101599-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.100.1-jitsi-11101599) and jetified-sendbird-calls-1.8.0-runtime (com.sendbird.sdk:sendbird-calls:1.8.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.AndroidVideoDecoder$FrameInfo found in modules jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.100.1-jitsi-11101599-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.100.1-jitsi-11101599) and jetified-sendbird-calls-1.8.0-runtime (com.sendbird.sdk:sendbird-calls:1.8.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.AudioDecoderFactoryFactory found in modules jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.100.1-jitsi-11101599-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.100.1-jitsi-11101599) and jetified-sendbird-calls-1.8.0-runtime (com.sendbird.sdk:sendbird-calls:1.8.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.AudioEncoderFactoryFactory found in modules jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.100.1-jitsi-11101599-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.100.1-jitsi-11101599) and jetified-sendbird-calls-1.8.0-runtime (com.sendbird.sdk:sendbird-calls:1.8.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.AudioProcessingFactory found in modules jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.100.1-jitsi-11101599-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.100.1-jitsi-11101599) and jetified-sendbird-calls-1.8.0-runtime (com.sendbird.sdk:sendbird-calls:1.8.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.AudioSource found in modules jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.100.1-jitsi-11101599-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.100.1-jitsi-11101599) and jetified-sendbird-calls-1.8.0-runtime (com.sendbird.sdk:sendbird-calls:1.8.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.AudioTrack found in modules jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.100.1-jitsi-11101599-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.100.1-jitsi-11101599) and jetified-sendbird-calls-1.8.0-runtime (com.sendbird.sdk:sendbird-calls:1.8.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.BaseBitrateAdjuster found in modules jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.100.1-jitsi-11101599-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.100.1-jitsi-11101599) and jetified-sendbird-calls-1.8.0-runtime (com.sendbird.sdk:sendbird-calls:1.8.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.BitrateAdjuster found in modules jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.100.1-jitsi-11101599-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.100.1-jitsi-11101599) and jetified-sendbird-calls-1.8.0-runtime (com.sendbird.sdk:sendbird-calls:1.8.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.BuiltinAudioDecoderFactoryFactory found in modules jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.100.1-jitsi-11101599-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.100.1-jitsi-11101599) and jetified-sendbird-calls-1.8.0-runtime (com.sendbird.sdk:sendbird-calls:1.8.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.BuiltinAudioEncoderFactoryFactory found in modules jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.100.1-jitsi-11101599-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.100.1-jitsi-11101599) and jetified-sendbird-calls-1.8.0-runtime (com.sendbird.sdk:sendbird-calls:1.8.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.CallSessionFileRotatingLogSink found in modules jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.100.1-jitsi-11101599-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.100.1-jitsi-11101599) and jetified-sendbird-calls-1.8.0-runtime (com.sendbird.sdk:sendbird-calls:1.8.0)
     Duplicate class org.webrtc.CalledByNative found in modules jetified-react-native-webrtc-1.100.1-jitsi-11101599-runtime (com.facebook.react:react-native-webrtc:1.100.1-jitsi-11101599) and jetified-sendbird-calls-1.8.0-runtime (com.sendbird.sdk:sendbird-calls:1.8.0)

==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
33 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 24 up-to-date
Caused by: com.android.builder.merge.DuplicateRelativeFileException: 2 files found with path 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjingle_peerconnection_so.so' from inputs:
```

Please help who knows answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is no longer relevant, but try to add the conflicting module to the exclude group:

```
implementation(project(':react-native-jitsi-meet')) {
   exclude group: 'com.facebook.react', module: 'react-native-webrtc'
}
```

In my case, I use react native